# Image hover transition to another image for portfolio

Tags: css

So I did this for my graphic design portfolio. And on my "Photo editing" page I made div which shows the photo before the editing, and when you hover on the image it shows the edited photo. The problem is that 50% of the time when I  hover on the photo it blinks to the photo instead of smooth transition.

CSS:

```
#photo {    
   background-image:url(../content/images/Editing/1.jpg);
   background-size:104%;
   -webkit-transition: background-image 0.3s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: background-image 0.3s ease-out;
   -o-transition: background-image 0.3s ease-out;
   transition: background-image 0.3s ease-out;  
}


#photo:hover {
   background-image:url(../content/images/Editing/1a.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the html part of the code ?

Comment: I found the solution myself. Instead of doing this with background image. I put the 2 images (absolute position overlapping) in DIV and on hover the top image is fading to 0 opacity and it works super smooth.

Comment: This is a very better solution, as the first one would only work in webkit browsers.

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the solution if you figured it out